# Manipulate indexed Interpolating Functions

Tags: manipulate

**MWE**

I have some data indexed by `gamma`. For each `gamma` I want to find the intersection points of two lists and plot the lists and the intersection points. I convert the two lists into two functions `ifun[gamma]` and `ifun2[gamma]` using `interpolation`, find their intersection using `FindRoot` and plot them. Instead of creating a separate plot for each gamma, I'd like to be able to throw that inside Manipulate. But I am running into trouble with Manipulate needing to explicitly define dependence on variables, as mentioned in the possible issues.

```
Table[ifun[gamma]=Interpolation[Table[{i, i^gamma}, {i, 1, 10}]], {gamma, 1, 2, 1}]
Table[ifun2[gamma]=Interpolation[Table[{i, gamma^gamma}, {i, 1, 10}]], {gamma, 1, 2, 1}]
Table[solE[gamma] = {x} /.FindRoot[ifun[gamma][x] == ifun2[gamma][x], {x, 0.15}], {gamma, 1,  2}]

Framed@Show[ListPlot[{#, ifun[1][#]} & /@ solE[1], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], Plot[{ifun[1][x], ifun2[1][x]}, {x, 0, 10}],RegionPlot[x < solE[1][[1]] && -5 < y < 5, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{Yellow, Opacity[0.2]}}]]
```

[image]

**Update2**

Ok so I did the indexing on the data and not on the functions, solved for the solutions outside the manipulate and just stored the points, interpolated inside Manipulate for plotting..and it works.

```
Table[data1[gamma] = Table[{i, i^gamma}, {i, 1, 10}], {gamma, 1, 2}]
Table[data2[gamma] = Table[{i, gamma^gamma}, {i, 1, 10}], {gamma, 1, 2, 1}]
Table[solE[gamma] = {x} /.FindRoot[Interpolation[data1[gamma]][x] ==
 Interpolation[data2[gamma]][x], {x, 0.15}], {gamma, 1, 2}]
```

This works:

```
Manipulate[fun = Interpolation[data1[gamma]];fun2 = Interpolation[data2[gamma]];Plot[{fun[x], fun2[x]}, {x, 1, 5}, Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large],   Point[{solE[gamma][[1]], fun[solE[gamma][[1]]]}]},  AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0}], {gamma, 1, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me if you tried working with my answer and if so what it did/didn't do?

Comment: Hey rm-rf, thanks for your answer. I tried working with it and it worked. I'll posted the working verison below in the question. The trick was to index the data and calculate a fresh interpolation inside the Manipulate, as opposed to indexing the interpolation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your data, so I can't run your code. Here's an example of using an `InterpolatingFunction` inside a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
    pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {a, b}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
    ifun = Interpolation[pts];
    Plot[ifun[x], {x, 0, 5}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
        Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[pts], Red, Point[{a, b}]}], 
    {{a, 3}, 0, 5}, {{b, 4}, 0, 5}]
```

Moving the sliders will recalculate the interpolating function for the new set of points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll post data in a sec and also try your method. The problem with me is that my interpolating functions look like `ifun[gamma][x]` where gamma $\in \{1,100\}$. I'll post a MWE in a few minutes.